# How to fill full screen of image on xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```html
 <FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
            android:id="@+id/imgThumbail"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

[image]
I don't want to set 500dp of width, 500dp of height.
I want to set full screen of image as above picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `500dp` to `fill_parent` (or `wrap_content`)

- `wrap_content`

The component just want to display big enough to enclose its content only.

- `fill_parent`

The component wants to display as big as its parent, and fill in the remaining spaces.

Note: `fill_parent` was renamed *`match_parent`* in API Level 8)

Comment: I tried your ways but the picture is small. This picture just have 500 px of width and height too.

Comment: does fill_parent support in API level 22?

Answer (score 2):

change the properties

```
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:layout_width="500dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

or

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

for API level= 8 for below 8